# Mongoose doesn't create subdocument from JSON array

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write a JSON object that contains both first-level data along with arrays into MongoDB.

What happens instead is all first-level data is stored, but anything contained in an array isn't. When logging the data the server receives, I see the entire object, which leads me to believe there's something wrong with my Mongoose code.

So for example if I send something like this:

```
issueId: "test1",
issueTitle: "testtest",
rows: [
  {order:1,data: [object]},
  {order:2,data: [object]},
]
```

Only the following gets stored:

```
issueId: "test1",
issueTitle: "testtest",
lastUpdated: Date,
```

I have the following model for Mongo:

```
//model.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var model = mongoose.Schema({

  issueId     : String,
  issueTitle  : String,
  lastUpdated : {type: Date, default : Date.now},

  rows  : [{
    order   : Number,
    data      : [
      {
        title   : String,
        text    : String,
        link    : String,
      }
    ]
  }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', model);
```

And the routing code, where I believe the problem likely is:

```
//routes.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Model = require('./model.js');
...
app.post('/api/data/update', function(req, res) {
  let theData = req.body.dataToInsert;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(theData,null,4));

  Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {issueId : theData.issueId},
    {theData},
    {upsert: true},
    function(err,doc){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(doc);
  });
});
```

As well, here's the part of the Angular controller storing the data. I don't think there's any problem here.

```
pushToServer = function() {
    $http.post('/api/data/update',{
        dataToInsert : $scope.dataObject,
    }).then(function successCallback(res){
        console.log("all good", JSON.stringify(res,null,3));
    }, function errorCallback(res){
        console.log("arg" + res);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first question in the mongoose FAQ:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html

> Mongoose doesn't create getters/setters for array indexes; without them mongoose never gets notified of the change and so doesn't know to persist the new value. The work-around is to use MongooseArray#set available in Mongoose >= 3.2.0.

```
// query the document you want to update
// set the individual indexes you want to update
// save the document
doc.array.set(3, 'changed');
doc.save();
```

**EDIT**

I think this would work to update all of the rows. I'd be interested to know if it does work.

```
let rowQueries = [];
theData.rows.forEach(row => {
    let query = Model.findOneAndUpdate({
        issueId: theData.issueId,
        'row._id': row._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            'row.$': row
        }
    });
    rowQueries.push(query.exec());
});

Promise.all(rowQueries).then(updatedDocs => {
    // updated
});
```

Comment: Arg okay. Is it possible to integrate this with the current Model API method?

Comment: This is a great question. I have not found a way to update all of the existing `rows` in a single update. I think you will need to update each row individually. I will update the answer with a way to do this.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that out. A bit disappointing that Mongoose doesn't support this...