# Similar $http requests after first get stuck in pending, then fail with NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm getting a really weird request problem with Angular and Node, and I can't find anything about it.

I have an Angular controller initially fetching data and putting it in $scope, which then also has a function that allows the controller to POST to the Node server to update the data. Upon updating, the server then sends the updated document.

The first update (POST) request works fine, and the data returns correctly. However, any subsequent requests get stuck in "Pending" (view in Chrome Dev Tools). They then fail after ~2 minutes, with an error in the console `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Only after failing do they show up in the Node console, but appear as:
`POST /api/document/update?m=0.6154590881151583 - - ms -`
where those `-`'s reflect the status code, request size, and time used to respond.

Angular controller:

```
pushToServer = function() {
$http.post('/api/document/update',{
    letter : $scope.document,
  }).then(function successCallback(res){
    console.log("all good" + JSON.stringify(res.data,null,3));
    $scope.document= res.data[0];
  }, function errorCallback(res){
    console.log("arg " + res);
  });
}
```

Node (Express) part

```
app.post('/api/document/update', function(req, res) {
    var letterParsed = req.body.letter;

    Documents.findOneAndUpdate(
      { issueId: letterParsed.issueId }, 
      { letterParsed }, 
      { upsert: true },
        function(err, doc) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });

    //FROM http://stackoverflow.com/a/38534012/1224973
    let rowQueries = [];
    letterParsed.rows.forEach(row => {
        var query = Documents.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            partId: letterParsed.partId,
            'rows.$._id': row._id
          }, {
            $addToSet: {
              'rows': row
            }
          }, {
            upsert: true
        });
        rowQueries.push(query.exec());
    });

    Promise.all(rowQueries).then(updatedDocs => {

      Documents.find({ partId: letterParsed.partId },
        function(err, doc) {
          if (err) { res.send(err); }
          res.json(doc)
        }
      );

    });
});
```

**EDIT:** 
Also, here is my Express configuration:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));               
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `.catch()` to your promise chain with a console output? the callback function takes 1 argument with the contained error.
In order to avoid such problems you need to catch every promise chain and let the client know what happened (a simple 500 request code will tell you where it failed). Like so `Promise.all(...).then(...).catch(function(err){ res.status(500).json({error: err}});`. Please do not returned detailed errors in production!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. However this is great to note though, thanks!

Comment: The reason the client freezes is because the second request crashes and no response is sent from the server (rejected/erroneous promise, uncaught exception etc...)

Comment: try logging req.body.letter, my guess is that you're doing an encoding in the first pass that you're missing afterwards (i.e. you may need to JSON.parse the response before you put it in the $scope object or something on those lines)

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'Document.find' part might be the problem. If you have an error, it will send err and then try to send doc, but you can't send two response. Just change to :

```
Documents.find({partId: letterParsed.partId},function(err, doc) {
   if (err) { 
      return res.send(err);
   }
   res.json(doc)
});
```

Comment: Not a solution, but I definitely should be doing this for best practice, thanks.

Comment: Not needed if you use promises. You `.catch()` the errors instead.